# Play video after presenting WKInterfaceController

Tags: swift2, xcode7, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

I have created one test app, in which I have dynamic number of videos.
I am presenting multiple interface controllers using API

```
presentControllerWithNames(controllers, contexts: contexts);
```

I have multiple numbers of pages on `watchApp`, based on the count of `controllers` array.

**There is a video on every interface controller,**

I had bind the `WKInterfaceMovie` object with

```
@IBOutlet var movie: WKInterfaceMovie!
```

and in `awakeWithContext()` I have written as follow to play movie,

```
override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
    super.awakeWithContext(context)

    //videoName will be depends on model object, I have passed
    let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("videoName",
            withExtension: "mp4")!


    self.movie.setMovieURL(url)
}
```

Video is not playing, once I tap on the play button of `WKInterfaceMovie` object on watch app.